# read file name and find particular string

Tags: c#

I have filename like

```
ChrysanthemumThumbnail82b09296a7c34373833050d362745a30.jpg
```

How can I find this string **ChrysanthemumThumbnail**

Comment: Is this string constant or it can be like this SomeTestString0872a3bd....jpg and in that case you should find SomeTestString?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method to read the file name without extension and then you can use `string.Contains` to check if it contains your string.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("ChrysanthemumThumbnail82b09296a7c34373833050d362745a30.jpg");
if(fileName.Contains("ChrysanthemumThumbnail"))
{
  //name found
}
```

if you want to see if the fileName starts with your string then you can use [string.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx)

```
if(fileName.StartsWith("ChrysanthemumThumbnail"))
{
 //file name starts with ChrysanthemumThumbnail
}
```

*(if you have the FileName already in a string then you don't need `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` it is only useful if you are trying to extract the filename from a path)*

Comment: why we need to get the file name since OP just want to check whether some thing is inside the path string, i would say its not necessary

Comment: @Saurabh, yes may be. The only thing I am expecting is that the file name is not exactly a file name, may be its a path, only my assumption, otherwise `sting.Contains` would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want something like:

```
string filename = "ChrysanthemumThumbnail82b09296a7c34373833050d362745a30.jpg"
bool result = filename.Contains("ChrysanthemumThumbnail");
```

Comment: Ah just seen that Habib posted a few moments before myself, please use his

Answer (score 1):

if the **ChrysanthemumThumbnail** always at start of the filename then just use 'StartWith'
, this will have better over contains which checks whole string

```
"ChrysanthemumThumbnail82b09296a7c34373833050d362745a30.jpg".StartsWith("ChrysanthemumThumbnail")
```

and if it can be at any location than use contains as suggested by Habib above

```
"ChrysanthemumThumbnail82b09296a7c34373833050d362745a30.jpg".Contains ("ChrysanthemumThumbnail")
```